# Join query when not in public schema

Tags: postgresql, outer-join

Sorry for the noob question.. but I cannot for the world of me figure out how to write a join when I am working on a scehma not in Public..

Writing right outer join in public schema

```
SELECT
    A.pka,
    A.c1,
    B.pkb,
    B.c2
FROM
    A
RIGHT OUTER JOIN B ON A .pka = B.fka;
```

I am trying this

```
SELECT
    A.pka,
    A.c1,
    B.pkb,
    B.c2
FROM
    schema.A
RIGHT OUTER JOIN B ON A .pka = B.fka;
```

Then i get an error "Relation 'B' does not exist"
I have tried a few other ways of doing it too without success

Thanks

EDIT, better example of my data.

This is my query, I get an error "Missing FROM clause entry for table t1

```
SELECT 
   t1.person_id
   t1.age
   t2.person_id
   t2.city
FROM
   not_public.t1 A
RIGHT OUTER JOIN not_public.t2 B ON A.person_id = B.person_id
```

Comment: In the SELECT list, you should refer to A and B, too, and **not** to the table names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    A.pka,
    A.c1,
    B.pkb,
    B.c2
FROM
    some_schema.table_a A
RIGHT OUTER JOIN other_schema.table_b B ON A.pka = B.fka
    ;
```

- if the schema is in the `search_path` you can omit the `schema_xxx.` prefix.
- the search_path is searched from left to right, the first match is used.
- for simplicity and readability, you can use correlation names ("aliases")  for the table references (here: `A` and `B`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, appreciate it a lot. I don't know why I find this so hard to grasp. Still have not solved it. I have edited my answer with a better example exactly to what I try to do, just modified the schedule and table names for simplicity. (both my tables are in the same schema).

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the FROM part of your query:

```
...
FROM not_public.t1 A
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN not_public.t2 B ...
```

You are using two tables t1 and t2. But you define an alias for both tables. `t1` is no called `A` and `t2` is no called `B`.

However in your SELECT list you use:

```
SELECT 
   t1.person_id
   t1.age
   t2.person_id
   t2.city
```

But because you "renamed" the tables t1 and t2 (through the alias) those names aren't available any more. Once you introduce an alias for a table, you have to **always** use that alias:

```
SELECT 
   a.person_id
   a.age
   b.person_id
   b.city
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Savior!